# Visual Studio Regions equivalent in FlexBuilder

Tags: flexbuilder

Is there something like regions in FlexBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex Builder does not have this functionality. I wish it did. There is a [feature request for it](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-16348), but it appears to be dead.